# Fast API accepting request from python client but not from postman

Tags: javascript, python, postman, fastapi

I have the following Fast API implementation that receives etxt and image data:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, File, UploadFile
from typing import List,Dict
import os
import campaign_begin
import shutil


app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/generate_chart")
async def generate_chart(
        company_retailer: str = Form(...),
        ad_lvl_count: int = Form(...),
        ad_level_name_list: list = Form(...),
        analytics_cat_type: str = Form(...),
        discount_flag: bool = Form(...),
        discount_adlevel: str = Form(...),
        discount_checkout_type: str = Form(...),
        optimization_checkout_type: str = Form(...),
        optimization_adlevel: str = Form(...),
        market_type_name_checkout: str = Form(...),
        a_b_test_flag: bool = Form(...),
        ab_adlevel: str = Form(...),
        tableau_name_checkout: str = Form(...),
        clip_count: int = Form(...),
        w_id: str = Form(...),
        ad_level_images: List[UploadFile] = File(...),
        clip_images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)

):

    for index, ad_image in enumerate(ad_level_images):
        with open(f"pic{index + 1}.jpg", "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(ad_image.file, buffer)

    for index, clip_image in enumerate(clip_images):
        with open(f"clip{index + 1}.jpg", "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(clip_image.file, buffer)

    # Call campaign_begin.generate_chart() function
    campaign_begin.generate_chart(
        company_retailer=company_retailer,
        ad_lvl_count=ad_lvl_count,
        ad_level_name_list=ad_level_name_list,
        analytics_cat_type=analytics_cat_type,
        discount_flag=discount_flag,
        discount_adlevel=discount_adlevel,
        discount_checkout_type=discount_checkout_type,
        optimization_checkout_type=optimization_checkout_type,
        optimization_adlevel=optimization_adlevel,
        market_type_name_checkout=market_type_name_checkout,
        a_b_test_flag=a_b_test_flag,
        ab_adlevel=ab_adlevel,
        tableau_name_checkout=tableau_name_checkout,
        clip_count=clip_count,
        w_id=w_id
    )


    return {"status": "success"}
```

When I send a Reuqest through a python client as below it works fine.

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8000/generate_chart/"

data = {
    "company_retailer": "Dummy_Company",
    "ad_lvl_count": 2,
    "ad_level_name_list": ["dummy_adlevel_1", "dummy_adlevel_2"],
    "analytics_cat_type": "Trolley + All",
    "discount_flag": True,
    "discount_adlevel": "dummy_adlevel_1",
    "discount_checkout_type": "Trolley + All",
    "optimization_checkout_type": "only-trolley",
    "optimization_adlevel": "dummy_adlevel_1",
    "market_type_name_checkout": "only-trolley",
    "a_b_test_flag": True,
    "ab_adlevel": "dummy_adlevel_1",
    "tableau_name_checkout": "only-trolley",
    "clip_count": 2,
    "w_id": '6485klo-5477'
}

files = [
    ("ad_level_images", ("pic1.jpg", open("pic1.jpg", "rb"), "image/jpeg")),
    ("ad_level_images", ("pic2.jpg", open("pic2.jpg", "rb"), "image/jpeg")),
    ("clip_images", ("clip1.jpg", open("clip1.jpg", "rb"), "image/jpeg")),
    ("clip_images", ("clip2.jpg", open("clip2.jpg", "rb"), "image/jpeg")),
]


response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)

print(response.json())
```

But when I send it through POSTMAN it does not go through with a message as : INFO:     127.0.0.1:58121 - "POST /generate_chart/ HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect
Did not find boundary character 137 at index 2
INFO:     127.0.0.1:58122 - "POST /generate_chart HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request

Any help in isolating the issue and solution idea will be highly appreciated

Comment: You're POST-ing to `/generate_chart/`, but you've registered `/generate_chart` as your endpoint. FastAPI therefore issues a 307 redirect, which I'm guessing isn't handled properly. Use the correct path (then one you've defined) and try again. (sidenote: I prefer having `/charts` as the REST path and using POST as the command to charts (i.e. to create / generate a chart, instead of having the path named  with `generate` in the URL). Use HTTP verbs to describe the action and the path to describe the resource to perform the verb on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the wrong port. FastAPI defaults to `127.0.0.1:8000` but your postman error messages say you're using `127.0.0.1:58121`

Edit: I may be mistaken `58121` might be an error code as the next error says `127.0.0.1:58122`. Still, the port might be a good thing to check because postman defaults to `127.0.0.1:5555` if I recall correctly.